# Plotting large datasets with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, bigdata

I have a large dataframe composed of more than 10 million rows containing both time and numerical variables. What I would like to do, is to use `ggplot` 's `geom_line()` to plot a time series but when I run the code it returns an empty plot with only x and y axis. However, an object is created under the type "large gg". Do you have any suggestions on how to deal with this problem?
I want to precise that reducing the number of rows it's not a viable option for me due to the fact that I am already trying to use a reduced dataframe of a shorter time window(around 3 millions of rows) and I still haven't solved the problem.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to summarize your data before plotting it. Assuming 10 million rows all represent unique times, then to actually show each point on a time series plot would require a retina display 500 metres across. If you somehow got your own compute to actually produce the plot on your own screen, it would necessarily be at most only a couple of thousand pixels wide, so the data will be "summarized" anyway, by whatever method your graphics device uses to squeeze the information into that number of pixels.

Comment: As @AllanCameron said, you can summarize/aggregate it. Even 3 millions of observations is way to much. Why not try and not to sample your data, then visualize the results until there will be no significant difference in plots.

Comment: I will try, maybe for visualization purposes it is better to reduce the data

Comment: The comments here are illustrating that for visualization purposes it's not just "better" - it's *not physically possible* to show without summarizing the data.